# RoR side content to appear on multiple pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

If you have a side table on your page with info from the database, and you want it to appear on several pages in your RoR app. How should this be done?
Let's say you output this data in a view, called LeftTableView or something like that.

Now in the, "/products/" view you want to display this data, and you also want to display it on "/products/12" and also on "/friends/" and so on.

How do you render out this "partial" view and bind the database data using the original controller only? Or... is it "better" to collect the data again from each controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumed, if you want appear "category" on navigation from database, keep in application_controller.rb

```
def navcategory
    @navcategories = Category.all
end
```

on products_controller.rb and friends_controller.rb , you just call navcategory with before_filter

```
before_filter :navcategory
```

and on layout

```
<% @navcategories.each do |category| %> 
....
....
....
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should setup your layout.  try the following (no css)

```
# application layout
<body>
  <div id='sidebar'>
    ... common content here
  </div>
  <div id='main'>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</body>
```